# Syntax error near '=' -- delete statement

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to add something so that things can be deleted from a table, though it says there is a syntax error near '=' and I can't seem to spot it. I know this isn't the most ideal way to be doing this, but I've been told to do it this way.

Here's what I've put:

```cs
Con.Open();
                    string query = "DELETE FROM tablepassengers WHERE passportno.=" + tbpassno.Text + ';';
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("deleted");
                    Con.Close();
                    populate();
```

Comment: You have a `.` after `passportno`, is that meant to be there? I would say this is where the error is.

Comment: @JayV its meant to be there since thats the name of the row in the table, but i can try change it and see if anything happens

Comment: If the column is called `passportno.`, then it needs to be wrapped in square brackets abd be. `[passportno.]`

Comment: While *"quoting"* it (with the square brackets) will fix the problem, you really should choose a better column name. Don't use anything in the column name you can't use as a variable name in C#. You'll still run into unexpected keywords, so look out for those; you'll still need to quote them.

Comment: @JayV ohhh okay i see, ill try that, i didnt know this + never got told this by any teachers, thank you!!

Comment: @madreflection i changed it anyway, but now the error changed and says error converting datatype varchar to numeric, though i dont understand since i declared when creating the table that its varchar

Comment: That's a whole different issue. Frankly, based on the 4 questions you've asked so far today, whatever you're using to learn is garbage. It's just telling you "do this" or "do that", not *teaching* you anything. You need to find something else.

Comment: @madreflection but then how come its working completely fine for them? sorry for bothering but i really dont get how it when everything is done in the same method as they have, it wont work on my end

Comment: "Working" is not the measure of good.

Comment: As Caius pointed out on your other question, you're being shown ***bad practices***.

Comment: @madreflection okay i understand that mindset, but genuinely the reasoning behind how something would run for them but not me?

Comment: For one thing, you're not being taught the fundamentals of syntax, so you're unable to see when you make a simple omission. You're not doing the same thing, but you're not being taught enough to be able to recognize it.

Comment: And it gets worse from there, because [SQL Injection](https://bobby-tables.com/) is a major security flaw, as Caius pointed out. You should never write code that way. This tutorial is *causing you harm from the very start*. It "works" until someone enters something you never imagined could be a problem, and then you're compromised.

Comment: I concur 100%, you are better off *not* learning SQL at all than learning via this, because then at least you'll have a chance in the future. You are actively learning extremely bad programming habits. I wish I could say the most egregious one is SQL injection (!) but it's not. It's the fact it is teaching "cargo-cult programming": doing things because "Youtube video said so" or "random dude on reddit/StackOverflow/etc said so" rather than understanding how the language works, and why certain practices are better or worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the `.` is meant to be there and that the column name is `passportno.`, this is where your problem is. It's not something that is expected, or recommended, but it is something that can be handled.

When using Sql you **really** should be using Parameters when constructing Sql statements in code. It is strongly suggested, not only is it good practice it will protect your applications from targetted attacks, to use `Parameters` -- Please read [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Change your code to look like this:

```
string query = "DELETE FROM tablepassengers WHERE [passportno.]=@passportNo;";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("passportNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = tbpassno.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
MessageBox.Show("deleted");
Con.Close();
```

Comment: ,, i changed it but theres an error saying argument3: cannot convert from string to int ,, i dont see where in the code there was even attempt for it to be converted

Comment: @yana When you created the table, what type did you assign to the column `passportno.` ? Was it a VarChar or Int ?

Comment: i assigned it to varchar, im not working with any int related data on this

Comment: @yana I made an update to the Parameter line, please give that a go

Comment: ohh ok that worked thank you, could i ask how changing it to `{ Value = tbpassno.Text });` fixed it?

Comment: Previous was just wrong, it didn't assign the `tbpassno.Text` to the parameter, but passed the text value to the `Size` parameter of the constructor. As this answer works for you, please [Accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

```
        try
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM tablepassengers WHERE passportno=" + tbpassno.Text;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
            Con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("deleted");

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).